# Ajax with Rails, appending div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to append div into my HTML using AJAX, system was developed in rails.
This is the content of js.erb file:

```
$('.posts').append("<%= j render 'post', posts: @post %>")
```

I really know that this file is being called by my code because if I change these line to `alert.('Hello')` the alert is shown on my web browser.

The problem is that the div is not being added.

Here is the code of my _post.html.erb

```
<%= div_for @posts do %>
  <p><b>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </b></p>
  <p><%= post.message %></p>
<% end %>
```

No errors is shown on terminal or in browser inspector.

[Edit 1] I saw now in chrome editor, server is posting one ajax to client side. The content is:

```
   $('.posts').append("")
```

Seems like render is not rendering, what is wrong with my code?

[Edit2]

The controller code is below. The method that is calling the ajax is the create.
I don't know if this make easier to see, but all this project is on github too:

https://github.com/ricardovsilva/twitter-rubyOnRails/

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.order('created_at desc')
        #respond_to :html
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.create(:message => params[:message])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @post.save
                format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
                format.js
            else
                flash[:notice] = "Message failed to save."
                format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The HTML's are:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "message_form" %>
<div id="posts">
    <%= render partial: @posts %>
</div>
```

**_message_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag("/posts", remote: true) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?")%><br>
    <%= text_field_tag(:message, nil, size: "44x6") %><br>
    <%= submit_tag("Update") %><br>
<% end %>
```

**_post.html.erb** (this is the one that I'm trying to render and send to client side)

```
<%= div_for @posts do %>
     <p><b>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </b></p>
     <p><%= post.message %></p>
 <% end %>
```

**layouts/application.html.erb** (here is where I'm trying to add the rendered div by ajax)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twitter</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"> 
    <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing render 'post' to render partial: 'post'

Comment: Nothing changed. I can see this in terminal (with or without partial word into code).  `Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Rendered posts/create.js.erb (4.0ms)`

Comment: shouldn't it be `render 'post', collection: @posts`

Comment: Won't work. I saw into network tab of chrome, and server is answer that code on my ajax requisition: `$('.posts').append("")`

Comment: @RicardoSilva can you post your controller code and also html where you want this div to append to

Comment: What is the controller returning to the browser?

Comment: I edited question and put all code of views and controller. Also I put the url of github where all project is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#posts').append("<%= j render 'post', post: @post %>")` is solution for your problem. Also _post.html.erb must be:

```
 <%= div_for post do %>
   <p><b>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago </b></p>
   <p><%= post.message %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but I didn't understand how `<%= div_for post do %>` works, can you explain?

Comment: Sure. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for) explanation of `div_for` helper. So what's the `post` in this context? Here `<%= j render 'post', post: @post %>` we render _post.html.erb partial and send to it @post object, available under the local variable `post`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should render `post` template [to string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) using [render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string) method.

Comment: I'm trying use it but I think that syntax is wrong because it giving me error. `$('.posts').append("<%= j render_to_string 'post', posts: @post %>")` , can you tell me how to do?